# dismiss all previous viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

It is given that I use :

```
LoginViewController 
MainTabController
```

I use `navigationController` to embed my tabbed `viewContollers` on `MainTabController`.

I call `self.dismiss` to cancel my `viewController`, back to the `LoginViewController`  page

If I add the `viewController` at the middle as below :

```
LoginViewController 
SelectViewController
MainTabController
```

How can I dismiss all previous view controllers, back to `LoginViewController` from my tabbed `viewController` ?

Comment: Try this UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: when you say `embed my tabbed viewcontollers` what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
   print("All controller dismissed successfully..")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an unwind segue. Unwind segues will generally figure out how to dismiss VCs for you.

Add an `@IBAction` method called `unwindFromLogin(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue)`. This method will be called when the unwind segue is performed.

In the storyboard, control+drag from login VC to the "Exit" of main tab VC, select the method you just wrote. Now you have added an unwind segue.

Give the segue an identifier and call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` with the identifier when you want to dismiss the login VC.